# Latex error of unknown language that isn't present anymore

Tags: pdftex

I run my Latex file using `pdflatex` and receive the following error message:

```
! Package babel Error: Unknown language `american'. Either you have
(babel)                misspelled its name, it has not been installed,
(babel)                or you requested it in a previous run. Fix its 
                       name,
(babel)                install it or just rerun the file, respectively.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.20 \select@language{american}
```

My .tex file starts with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
...
```

I removed the american babel package and replaced it by the ngerman package. After this I got a package babel error although the american package is already removed.

How could I fix this error and get the code compiled?

Answer (score 3):

I removed the created .aux file and after running `pdflatex <filename>` again there is no error anymore and the PDF is built properly.